# How to fill null values with appropriate values based on the datatype of the columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a `csv` in `pandas`. Now I need to fill the empty values and dump it to a table. So this is what I do.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:******@localhost:****/database')
df.to_sql("my_table", engine)
```

Now the problem is for the columns that have `integer` values along with few missing values, `pandas` fills empty `string` for those missing values. So when dumping it to a table, `pandas` classifies the column type as a `string` and dumps it to a table. So this column gets `text` as datatype (in case of `postgres`) as opposed to not doing anything to fill the missing values and the column being correctly classified as an `integer` or `double precision` (in case of `postgres`) which is a correct behaviour.

However this is not a problem for columns that have `string` values along with missing values since those missing values would be assigned an empty `string` anyway and won't affect the column type.

Now what I want is a way to fill empty values with `0` for those columns that have integer or float values and `''` (empty string) for those columns that have `string` values. How do I do it in pandas?

**Note:** Some columns can also be `datetime` for which I don't plan to fill it with anything as of now.

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to do this.

**CASE 1: You Have `numeric` and `string` Columns only**

**Note**: This assume you only want to fill the N/A values of column with string data type with `' '` and there rest (numeric columns) with `0`.

```
df.transform(lambda x: x.fillna('') if x.dtype == 'object' else x.fillna(0))
```

---

**CASE 2: You Need Custom Functions to Handle More Data Type**

If you want to handle more data types, you can make your own function and apply it to fill the null values.

```
def fill_null_values(value):
  dtype = value.dtype
  result = ''

  # to handle string data type
  if dtype  == 'object':
    result = ''

  # to handle numeric data type
  elif ('int' in dtype ) or ('float' in dtype ):
    result = 0

  # add more cases to handle more data type

  return value.fillna(result)

data.transform(fill_null_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
np.random.seed(47)

df = pd.DataFrame({'attend' : np.random.choice(['yes', 'no', 'some', np.nan], 100),
                  'other_random_col' : np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', np.nan], 100),
                  'int_col' : np.random.sample(100),
                  'none' : [np.nan] * 100})

#checks all rows where columns are numbers and fills NaN with 0
df.loc[:, df.dtypes == np.number] = df.fillna(0)
```

Should also work for strings but **note**:

> - To select strings you must use the `object` dtype, but note that
>     this will return *all* object dtype columns